# Select all those rows whose certain columns (and not all the columns) have specific values

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to select all those rows whose certain columns (and not all the columns) have specific values.

For example:

```
SELECT * from TABLE1
WHERE col_A in (1,2)
   or col_B in (1,2)
   or col_C in (1,2)
```

What is the best way to achieve it?

Comment: What's wrong with the query you posted?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to achieve it?

The best way is to use the query you are already using:

```
SELECT *
from   TABLE1
WHERE  col_A in (1,2)
or     col_B in (1,2)
or     col_C in (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * from TABLE1 WHERE col_A in (&v1,&v2) or col_B in (&v3,&v4) or col_C in (&v5,&v6)